# nginx with ssl compile error

Tags: ssl, nginx, compilation

I'm hoping one of you have figured this out already.

I have been trying to compile nginx with ssl support and it is failing at make with the following error:

src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:1690:31: error: variable ‘c’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make[1]: *** [objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o] Error 1
make[1]:**  Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/steve/tarballs/nginx-1.0.4'
make: ** [build] Error 2

Here are my configure arguments:

./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-http_realip_module --pid-path=/opt/nginx/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module

Anyone have any idea whats going on here? I get the same error when pointing --openssl-dir to the source of openssl...

Thanks in advance... Let me know if need to give more info

Comment: Do you have the *devel* version of `openssl` installed, not just the basic version? If on Fedora, you could check by `yum list openssl*` - on my system, I'd see both `openssl.x86_64` and `openssl-devel.x86_64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the removal of -Werror and -Wall in the make file after configure the issue was solved. it turned out to be a bug in the c code itself. yet unsure if this is hacking around or solving the problem.

according to google those tags will treat warnings as errors and was causing the build to fail